# Должно выводиться top, но не выводится

Tags: python

```
import keyboard
import os
import sys
from msvcrt import getch
n = ['b\'d\'', 'op_browser', 'os.system("C:\\Users\\scher\\AppData\\Local\\Yandex\\YandexBrowser\\Application\\browser.exe")']
print(n)
while True:

    print(n)
    pressedKey = msvcrt.getch()
    if pressedKey in n:
        ###############3

        print("top")

    else :
        print(b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`msvcrt.getch()` возвращает байтовую строку, например `b'd'` при нажатии кнопки `d`, а у вас в списке строка `'b\'d\''`

Рабочий пример:

```
import msvcrt

n = [b'd']

while True:
    pressed_key = msvcrt.getch()
    if pressed_key in n:
        print('top')
```

В текущем виде ваш код еще выдаст ошибку на `msvcrt.getch()`. Чтобы работало (не выдавало ошибку), нужно или просто `getch()`, или исправить импорт `from msvcrt import getch` на просто `import msvcrt` (как в моем примере).

Также в ветке `else` у вас вывод неинициализированной переменной `b`.

Comment: А у меня вопрос ещё! У меня есть текстовый файл в котором записано:                                   
b'd'
op_browser
os.system("C:\Users\scher\AppData\Local\Yandex\YandexBrowser\Application\browser.exe")
Как мне сделать так что бы b'd' когда я преобразую этот документ в список было [b'd'] ???

Comment: @ЧернышевСергей, объясните русским языком что вы хотите получить (а не то что вы пытаетесь сделать). Лучше отдельным вопросом.

Comment: я изменил вопрос

Comment: Не нужно полностью менять вопрос (это автоматически делает существующие ответы неправильными), создайте новый.

Comment: я создал !!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: простите я просто первый раз задаю вопрос на этом сайте